# In PHP need all unique combinations of multiple arrays

Tags: php, laravel, algorithm

First, I have looked through dozens of similar questions/answers on this site an have not found any type of solution I could use or modify to use for this problem. There are a lot of things that come into play with this. I got close but it kept running out of memory or other resource so here I am.

I need to create a function that takes a set of arrays and returns all combinations with a specific set of rules. So to start I pull the arrays. There are 9 to start of all various lengths. 4 of the arrays are duplicate set of 4 other individual arrays. Heres how I pull the arrays to start, just so you have an idea of how the data looks.

```
$prodA1 = Products::where('type','a')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$prodA2 = Products::where('type','a')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$prodB1 = Products::where('type','b')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$prodB2 = Products::where('type','b')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$prodC1 = Products::where('type','c')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$prodC2 = Products::where('type','c')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$prodD1 = Products::where('type','d')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$prodD2 = Products::where('type','d')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$prodE = Products::where('type','e')->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

I need all set of arrays to be array('prodA1','prodA2','prodB1','prodB2','prodC1','prodC2','prodD1','prodD2','prodE') with the values being IDs bot the name of the array.

Each returned array must be unique

Each individual array can have as many as 96 ids but they all vary

I found the below function which if I add a take(5) to the above so it limits the output seems to produce at least all the combinations which I can then apply other rules to but it takes forever to run. This is the closest I have gotten though, there has to be a faster solution to this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public function combinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
        if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
            return array();
        }
        if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
            return $arrays[$i];
        }

        // get combinations from subsequent arrays
        $tmp = $this->combinations($arrays, $i + 1);

        $result = array();

        // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
        foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
            foreach ($tmp as $t) { 
                    $result[] = is_array($t) ? 
                        array_merge(array($v), $t) :
                        array($v, $t);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

EDIT:
The input wound be a set of 9 arrays with ids in them. For instance:

```
$prodA1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$prodA2 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$prodB1 = array(6,7,8,9);
$prodB2 = array(6,7,8,9);
$prodC1 = array(10,11,12,13);
$prodC2 = array(10,11,12,13);
$prodD1 = array(14,15,16,17);
$prodD2 = array(14,15,16,17);
$prodE = array(18,19,20,21);
```

returns would look something like

```
array(1,2,6,7,10,11,14,15,18)
array(1,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)
```

so all the results would be unique, each one would contain 9 values made up of 2 prodA,2 prodB, 2 prodC, 2 prodD and 1 prodE

Hope that clears it up a little.

Comment: There's a great library -- [bpolaszek/cartesian-product](https://github.com/bpolaszek/cartesian-product) -- that I have used for this task before, and I recommend it. How you'd implement it in this situation is a little unclear, could you edit your comment to explain what you're trying to achieve exactly? I'm struggling to clearly understand, if you could include example input and expected output that would be very helpful.

Comment: So, `96^9` combinations?

Comment: @sam edited as requested

Comment: Maybe it's normal that you run out of memory and/or your script takes forever to run. There are a LOT of combinations of all those values. Let's say you're using a mean half of the available combinations (so 9 arrays of 48 values). Your total combination count is then 48x48x48x48x48x48x48x48x48 or 48^9, which amounts to 1352605460594688 combinations. Basically, just take the amount of numbers in one array and put it to the power of 9 and ask you if that number isn't too big.

Comment: @vivek_23 each initial inputed array can have up to 96 ids in them but my testing so far has only resulted in 40 max, its just the possibility of 96 per does exist. then that would be 9 times and all unique combinations in between

Comment: 40^9 still equals around 262 trillion combinations.

Comment: @linkboss no doubt. Im not saying this isn't normal at all, I would expect any average computer not be able to do this the way I am doing it. I have considered creating a temp table in the database to house the info instead of trying to save in an array or possibly applying rules to it while it is being created but have had no luck.

Comment: @Scott So, it would take a lot of time to compute. Algorithm is not the issue, but perhaps it's purpose. Can you let me know why you need so many combinations?

Comment: @Scott No it's not. Putting in perspective, a computer with 16 GB of RAM has the possibility to write 16 billion 256-capped numbers in its memory. No way you can do operations in the realm of trillions of possibilities in any reasonable amount of time, and (if you simplify it a lot) at let's say 4 GHz it can do 4 billion computations a second (in pure assembly, without counting any memory operation to actually store data), so computing 262 trillion operations takes at least 65500 seconds based on that, which equals about 18 hours. That gives a very rough idea of what you're asking.

Comment: @linkboss I should have phrased that differently. I agree with everything you said. Spot on. I know its possible but with the numbers you just posted not worth it in its current state for what im trying to achieve. I can certainly limit it to make it more efficient, I just through maybe there was some type of algorithm or theory I could apply that would make this somewhat efficient.

Comment: @vivek_23 what im trying to accomplish, and this will be modified to fit my other needs, is to create a function that will take arrays of IDs of athletes in there perspective sports and create all possible lineup combinations. It needs to be broad enough to adjust up or down. So for instance if this was baseball I could give an array for leftfield,center,rightfield,catcher,1st base ect and output all possibly lineups with one id from each position that is unique. Does that help? Even a scaled down version with no more than 20 elements in each array would get me started.

Comment: @Scott Lazy loading seems a good idea to me. Because you can't throw so many combinations at once.

Comment: Lazy loading doesn't even solve it for me, in its most pure smallest form, just the ID of each athlete, this cannot be done in a reasonable amount of time. My opinion on that is questioning yourself on wether this huge amount of data is just a transitory phase in a bigger algorithm (to get for example the most capable team to crush everyone at fantasy football) or an end in itself. If it is just transient data, I would advise you to revise your whole algorithm using your set of rules to not have to compute all possibilities at any moment. Basically, reduce the set size with your rules first.

Comment: @linkboss going by what you said, what about reducing it to at most initial arrays of no more than 8. I can certainly cut down the initial data to only specific ids I need for each set. Even with that though I am still trying to wrap my head around a function that would produce what im originally looking for.

Comment: Well, 9 sets of 8 elements still gives you 134 million combinations. More "manageable".